# can't connect to method in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using asp.net web api. I'm trying to have a positive response from the server, however program is not seeing one of the methods in the controller. It goes into the controller constructor, but not further. 
The response is

> Status Code 404, Reason Phrase: Not Found.

I understand that it can be a typo in the method name/parameters/whatever, but everything seems fine for me. I could have overlooked something though.

And API is working fine, I've tried it with different method.

Here is the controller method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/ClientFiles/GetScanStatus")]
    [ActionName("GetScanStatus")]
    private Tuple<bool, bool?, bool?> GetScanStatus(int scanTypeId, int clientId, int inventoryId)
    {
        //businessLogic here 


        return new Tuple<bool, bool?, bool?>(false, null, null);
    }
```

The method that calls the controller:

```
  public static async Task<Tuple<bool, bool?, bool?>> GetScanStatus(int scanTypeId, int clientId, int inventoryId)
  {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 90);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{ConnectionURL}api/ClientFiles/GetScanStatus/?scanTypeId={scanTypeId}&clientId={clientId}&inventoryId={inventoryId}").ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Tuple<bool, bool?, bool?>>();
                return result;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

`response.RequestedUri` was

```
http://localhost:61372/api/ClientFiles/GetScanStatus/?scanTypeId=26&clientId=12&inventoryId=25482
```

Comment: Your controller method is private... nothing will be able to see it.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. That's what I overlooked :P

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: There we go, added as an answer... I trip myself up with errors like this all the time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code it looks like your controller method is `private`, and therefore not visible!

Make the method `public`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/ClientFiles/GetScanStatus")]
[ActionName("GetScanStatus")]
public Tuple<bool, bool?, bool?> GetScanStatus(int scanTypeId, int clientId, int inventoryId) {
    //...
}
```

and I think it will work.